# OneNote API Create Page C#

Tags: c#, onenote-api

I am trying to create new pages through the OneNote API. My question is, do I have to use the Live SDK to create a new page or can I just use the access token I got from my OneNote API Dekstop Applications? Here is the code I have for creating the new page:

```
        private async Task CreateTestPage()
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "tokenString");


                string sampleHtml = @"<html>
    <head>
        <title>A sample page</title> 
    </head>
    <body>  
        <p>This is a page that has some info</p>
    </body>
</html>";

                var createMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _pagesEndPOint)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(sampleHtml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html")
                };

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(createMessage);
                response = await client.SendAsync(createMessage);

                await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();   
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
```

I am not getting any errors thrown, but it is not creating any new page when I run the application. Also, I am creating this in a Word Add in so I call this method CreateTaskPage() inside the Add In method.

Any help on getting this up and running would be VERY helpful, thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use the MS Graph API and SDKs - you can do everything you can with the OneNote API with it, but their SDKs/docs are more extensive (they even have C# SDKs)

You can try it out in the console (check the OneNote section)

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Will I be able to write tables onto onenote from the Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: Yes. On your create page request HTML, you can specify all the HTML that is supported in the OneNote API, including tables.

Comment: Last question, could you direct me to the page where it shows the example in C#? I can't seem to find it

Comment: There's no C# specific example, though the SDK supports it.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/onenote_post_pages